# Short story where a doctor wakes early from hyper sleep and slowly cannibalises the rest of the crew?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

Heard this as an audio book a while back and loved it! A doctor wakes up early on a long space flight and realizes that there aren't enough rations to last the rest of the trip. Eventually, close to starvation, he wakes another crew member and kills and eats him... as time goes by he refines his methods and keeps the other crew members alive longer as he slowly harvests their flesh so that the meat stays 'fresh' longer... well written and truly creepy! Any help with finding this story is much appreciated!

Comment: This would've been a much better plot for Passengers.

Comment: Probably not the one you're looking for, but there's a very similar subplot in the novel "Black Man" (also known as "Thirteen") by Richard Morgan - however the person responsible isn't a doctor: [link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40448.Thirteen)

Answer (score 12):

The title is [The Taste of Starlight](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1184450), written by John R. Fultz.

A scientist is pre-maturely awoken from suspended animation aboard a spaceship due to cryo-pod failure. He quickly realizes he still has 16 months before the ship reaches the planet colony it was sent to resupply/help, but only has 3 months worth of food. He has to survive in order to install some ultra violet boost thingy on the target planet, because it orbits a red dwarf that doesn't emit sufficient light for the crops to grow. So he starts nibbling on his crewmates, naturally.

It must be this one, I was looking for it myself and stumbled across this on lightspeed magazine.
It's a thrilling read, but Kristoffer Tabori also does a great job narrating the short story, which can be heard [here on the Lightspeed website](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-taste-of-starlight/).

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Just so you're aware, link-only answers like this are generally frowned upon, as links tend to die off over time. Could you explain how this story matches the description in the question, please?

Comment: Can you add the title and author an a summary of the element it contains that match the story OP is looking for?

Comment: Hi :) Yeah, thankies - I was in a rush and forgot all that, should be there now though.