# Story about a man waking up early from cryogenic sleep and eats his crewmates to survive

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

There is a ship travelling to a planet for a reason I do not remember. On their voyage, one man (let's call him Bill) is woken up a couple of years early. The ship was only stocked with food to last all of them a couple months. Bill does his best to ration the food but after sometime, he runs out. He still has a long time to go before they reach their destination. He becomes so hungry that he resorts to eating one of the sleeping crewmates. As he opens their pod, they wake up and they struggle for their lives. Bill eventually prevails and ends up killing him.

He becomes addicted to human flesh that he overeats like never before. After eating, he loses a lot of meat due to it becoming rotten. So as he continues to kill/eat his crewmates, he becomes better at the whole process. Faster forward, he basically has killed everyone on the ship as they approach their destination. When they finally land, he expects a warm greeting but is met with a flood of people that only want one thing. Him.

Comment: Almost certainly the same story as [Short story where a doctor wakes early from hyper sleep and slowly cannibalises the rest of the crew?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170513/short-story-where-a-doctor-wakes-early-from-hyper-sleep-and-slowly-cannibalises)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story where a doctor wakes early from hyper sleep and slowly cannibalises the rest of the crew?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170513/short-story-where-a-doctor-wakes-early-from-hyper-sleep-and-slowly-cannibalises)

Comment: @Pete - According to the rules of the site as I understand them, a story ID thread should only be closed as a duplicate if the question is asking about the same story as another question, and both questions have answers which have been confirmed to be correct by the respective OPs. In this case, neither thread has an answer that has been confirmed to be correct by the OP. As such, neither one should be closed.

Comment: For the last bit, is he a hero?   Or are they cannibal/zombies?

Answer (score 22):

*The Taste of Starlight* by John R. Fultz, published in the *[Lightspeed: Year One](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12114336-lightspeed)* magazine in 2011.

[image: The book cover with the title: Light Speed.]

You can read the full story [here](https://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-taste-of-starlight/), but [here's a brief summary](https://fullofwords.com/short-stories/short-stories-of-the-week-driftings-and-the-taste-of-starlight/) from fullofwords.com:

> The Taste of Starlight tells the story of a doctor on a seven-year interstellar mission to a far-off colony. A systems malfunction causes his cryopod to open early, and he becomes the only person awake on the ship with more than a year left to go before landfall. He discovers that there aren’t enough emergency rations to last him for the whole trip… and I’m sure you’ve figured out where this is going.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.